# Mysql, how to join and group two columns on different tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables in mysql:

```
table name = 'static':
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | username | ip        |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | foo      | 172.0.0.1 |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 2  | bar      | 172.0.0.2 |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 3  | baz      | 172.0.0.3 |
+----+----------+-----------+

table name = 'dynamic':
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | username | ip        |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | bill     | 172.0.0.1 |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 2  | ben      | 172.0.0.4 |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 3  | hen      | 172.0.0.5 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

What I want, is to merge columns 'ip' in both tables together, then group by the ip, and return the quantity of identical ip's that were grouped.

Example result:

```
+-----------+----------+
| ip        | quantity |
+-----------+----------+
| 172.0.0.1 | 2        |
+-----------+----------+
| 172.0.0.2 | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
| 172.0.0.3 | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
| 172.0.0.4 | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
| 172.0.0.5 | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a join but UNION ALL and then grouping:

```
select t.ip, count(*) quantity from (
  select ip from static
  union all
  select ip from dynamic
) t
group by t.ip
```

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly. Do you mind explaining what union does differently compared to a join?

Comment: A union of 2 tables contains all the rows of the 2 tables. A join matches rows from 1 table to rows of the other table on a condition and the result is rows combined of columns from both tables, so if a table has 3 columns and the other 4 columns the result has 7 columns or any columns that you select.